# ionic-angular tabs module not found

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I updated my angular libraries and for some strange reasons my ionic angular project is now broken. the error i see on running the app in the console is

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './tabs/tabs.module'
Error: Cannot find module './tabs/tabs.module'
    at main.js:1
    at e.invoke (polyfills.js:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.js:1)
    at e.invoke (polyfills.js:1)
    at t.run (polyfills.js:1)
    at polyfills.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at w (polyfills.js:1)
    at w (polyfills.js:1)
    at polyfills.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at t.runTask (polyfills.js:1)
    at _ (polyfills.js:1)
```

I have tried nuking nodes_module and doing fresh npm i. but no luck. I created a new test project with tabs template and tried to compare and dont see anything different.

i did check specifically tabs.module.ts . what else i should i look to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like upgrading messed up things and i added the below entry to the app-routing.module.ts file

```
 { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
```